# How to return from a method that's calling a closure

Tags: groovy

I have a closure that I'm passing into a method(`doExecute`). I'd like to return from the calling method(`getResellableState`) if the shouldExecute variable in the `doExecute` method is passed a value of true.

I understand that a return inside a closure returns only from the closure, not from the method that called it, so I'm trying to understand how to return from the `getResellableState` method that called the closure.

Here's the code I'm trying to return from:

```
ResellableState getResellableState(Ticket ticket) {
    int counter = 0
    doExecute(!isResellable(ticket.inventoryLineItem.inventoryAccess), counter) { int count ->
        return createResellableState(com.ticketfly.commerce.enums.ResellableState.FEATURE_DISABLED, count)
    }
    ...
}
```

Here's the deExecute method:

```
private doExecute(boolean shouldExecute, int counter, block) {
    counter++
    if (shouldExecute) {
        block(counter)
    }
}
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

#### 1. Return some signal

The `getResellableState` needs to know whether it should keep executing the method or not, thus you need some kind of signalling:

```
ResellableState getResellableState(Ticket ticket) {
    int counter = 0
    if (!doExecute(!isResellable(ticket.inventoryLineItem.inventoryAccess), counter) { int count ->
        return createResellableState(com.ticketfly.commerce.enums.ResellableState.FEATURE_DISABLED, count)
    }) {
        ...
    }
}
```

#### 2. Throw an exception

Your `doExecute` may throw an exception to stop the flow, but note this also needs proper handling

```
ResellableState getResellableState(Ticket ticket) {
    int counter = 0
    doExecute(!isResellable(ticket.inventoryLineItem.inventoryAccess), counter) { int count ->
        try {
            return createResellableState(com.ticketfly.commerce.enums.ResellableState.FEATURE_DISABLED, count)
        } catch (e) { throw e }
    })
    ...
}
```

Comment: I tried returning a signal from the `getResellableState` method but it doesn't seem to work as `getResellableState` doesn't return. It just goes on to the next if statement.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
ResellableState getResellableState(Ticket ticket) {
    int counter = 0
    def state = doExecute(!isResellable(ticket.inventoryLineItem.inventoryAccess), counter) { int count ->
        return createResellableState(com.ticketfly.commerce.enums.ResellableState.FEATURE_DISABLED, count)
    }
    if (state instanceof ResellableState) {
        return state
    }
    ...
}
```